# geetools:batch not working in 2022 Google Earth Engine (GEE) (solved)

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, landsat-8, geemap

I am pretty new to GEE, but somehow find my way to get an imagecollection that I want to export. Then I find **geetools:batch** with this answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com).

**Objective and Problem:** what I want to do is to exporting an imagecollection (60images) automatically if possible. When I follow this geetools:batch methods, my GEE throw me an error stating `In users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch Line 133: collection.toList is not a function`.

Here is the code that I executed and the GEE link [https://code.earthengine.google.com/6fe94ef8660e66eceec51e8d98518b77]:

```
// import 12 points coordinates csv file
var nesttest = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-sihaochen/assets/NESTTEST");

// create bufferPoints function
 function bufferPoints(radius, bounds) {
   return function(pt) {
     pt = ee.Feature(pt);
     return bounds ? pt.buffer(radius).bounds() : pt.buffer(radius);
   };
 }

// create 500m buffers for each point
var roi = nesttest.map(bufferPoints(500, false));
print(roi.size(), "roi size");
print(roi.getInfo());

// feature collection to List
var roigeometrylistfeature = roi.toList(roi.size());
print(roigeometrylistfeature, 'featurecollection to list');
// get first-index item in a list and conver to geometry
var roilist_0 = ee.Feature(roigeometrylistfeature.get(0));
var roilist_0_g = roilist_0.geometry();
print(roilist_0, roilist_0_g);

var start_year = 2016;
var end_year = 2020;
var years = ee.List.sequence(start_year, end_year);

function best_image_each_year (year){
  var start_date = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 01, 01);
  var end_date = start_date.advance(1, 'year');
  var image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_TOA")
              .filterBounds(roilist_0_g)
              .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
              .select(['B3', 'B2', 'B1'])
              .sort("CLOUD_COVER")
              .first()
              .clip(roilist_0_g);
  return image;
}

var roilist_0_g_2016_2020 = years.map(best_image_each_year);
print(roilist_0_g_2016_2020);


//\\ Exporting data
// batch download https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/wiki/Batch; https://code.earthengine.google.com/dcee89acbe86bca49ce72605a9f5a7fe;
// https://code.earthengine.google.com/15f748dffa93c031eac646e449981d9d

var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(roilist_0_g_2016_2020, 'Landsat07', {scale: 30});
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this **..not a function error**?

Here is the [Link](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/blob/master/batch) for geetools:batch documentation.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. You have a number of question marks here, which makes it difficult to determine the focus of your Question.

Comment: Thanks @Vince, I will take a tour. I guess I have found a solution myself. For those might share a same situation, please make sure convert your filtered images to a image collection. `var roilist_0_g_2016_2020_col = ee.FeatureCollection(roilist_0_g_2016_2020);`

Answer (score 1):

`toList` is a method that exists on collections but not lists. We can reasonably conclude that `batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive` probably wants a collection (it's in the name), but you're passing a list. So, you can convert the list to a collection.

```js
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(
  ee.ImageCollection(roilist_0_g_2016_2020),
  'Landsat07',
  {scale: 30}
);
```

Comment: yes!! that's how I did, and now it works! thanks for your answer..